# Software for emulating networks and NAT

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, nat, linux-networking

I am working on a software that I need to test with different types of NAT, and I would like to set up a test environment I can reconfigure in different NAT modes.

I would like to have:

```
(a)---192.168.3.0/24[NAT] ---- 192.168.1.0/24 ---- [NAT]192.168.2.0/24---(c)
```

This layout would allow me to connect to devices from two NATed networks, that is what I need to perform some testing.

I have a server with Windows 2012 I would like to add two additional NICs ( a and b), but what software may I use to create those networks and the different types of NAT?

Other option, is to install Linux. Is still `iptables` the right tool for the job? Would it be possible to do what I want?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install VirtualBox (or some other virtualization provider)
2. Install [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) within a VirtualBox machine
3. Configure whatever network topology/routing you want to test
4. Profit! :)

> Is still iptables the right tool for the job? Would it be possible to
>   do what I want?

With a linux system, iptables would be part of the solution, yes, but if you're asking this level of question, you're likely going to have a hard time getting all the pieces in place.

Comment: I worked a lot with iptables creating routers, firewalls etc...  almost 10 years ago! I hope I can get going. pfSense looks pretty neat. Thanks!

Comment: pfSense in a VM is perfect for these sorts of applications.